# Auth0 Credentials object's Expire date property is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, jwt, auth0

I am using Auth0 SDK version 1.1.0. I am using **openid name email offline_access** scopes. I am successfully getting credential object in the success response. But credential's expiresIn object always nil.

```
var parameters = [String: String]()
parameters["deviceToken"] = "This is a device token from iOS simulator"
parameters["device"]      = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.description ?? UIDevice.current.name

Auth0.authentication().login(usernameOrEmail: usernameField.text!, password: passwordField.text!,
                             multifactorCode: nil, connection: "Username-Password-Authentication",
                             scope: "openid name email offline_access",
                             parameters: parameters).start({ (result) in
                                switch result {
                                case .success(let credentials):
                                    WSDataManger.sharedInstance.saveCredentials(credentials: credentials)
                                    print("credentail expire date is \(credentials.expiresIn)")

                                case .failure(let error):
                                    print("Failed to login: \(error.localizedDescription)")


                             })
}
```

How to get the expiresIn date?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for that?

Comment: @EderYif       Please check the solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**: 
You can decode the idToken and you will get the `exp` and `iat`value. `expires_in` can be calculated by the difference between the exp and iat claims of the JWT.

```
/// Decode the JWT token
func decodeJwtToken() -> String? {

    let tokenInfoArray = self.components(separatedBy: ".")
    if tokenInfoArray.count >= 2 {
        // First object array contain {"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}
        //Second Object is required information
        let encodedBase64String = tokenInfoArray[1].base64String;
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: encodedBase64String, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let decodedString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return nil }
        //remove null terminator Occurrences.
        let nullTerminatedString = decodedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\0", with: "")
        //remove whitespace Occurrences.
        let formattedString = nullTerminatedString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        return formattedString
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Method 2**: You can use the Auth0 delegation API to get expires_in and store it in defaults or Auth0 Keychain.

```
  //  Renewing the expired token
func renewToken() {
    let payload = [
        "refresh_token" : defaults.value(forKey: "refresh_token"),
       "id_token" : defaults.value(forKey: "id_token"),
       "scope": "openid name email offline_access" ]
    Auth0.authentication().delegation(withParameters: payload).start { (result) in
        print(result)
        switch result {
        case .success(let credentials):
            if let value = credentials["id_token"] {
                defaults.setValue(value, forKey: "id_token")
            }
            if let value = credentials["expires_in"] as? Double {
                print("expires_in timestamp \(value)")
                //Calculate timestamp to date format.
            }
            defaults.synchronize()
        case .failure(let error):
              //Handle Error
              print(error)
        }
    }
}
```